# google plugin services gives me an error

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, service

In gradle, at the end, I'm trying to insert this line
*apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'*
but whenever I sync the file I get this error:

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
  >   Searched Location: 
  >   C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyListViewApp\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
  >   C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyListViewApp\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
  >   C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyListViewApp\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
  >   C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyListViewApp\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  >   C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyListViewApp\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
  >   C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyListViewApp\app\google-services.json
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error says `File google-services.json is missing`, you have not included google-service json file in your project. Which is configuration file needed if you use any google api.

**To include google-service.json in your project**

Please go to this URL :

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Choose your Options and  finally you will be able to download

`google-service.json` file

copy that file and paste it Into

`YourProjectName/app`  Directory and build project.